# Number of days, ignoring hours and minutes, in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to calculate the number of days since a given date.

```
today = new Date();
time = today - mydate;
days = Math.floor(time / (1000*60*60*24));
```

This returns the correct value only if mydate is set to a time before the current time. In other words, if mydate is yesterday at 10 pm and I run this in the morning, I get 0 when I want 1.

Comment: it's because of `floor()`. Try to chage with `ceil()`. BTW actually a whole day isn't passed yet

Comment: But wouldn't I then have the opposite problem: If I'm comparing today evening to yesterday morning I'll get 2!